# Optional ways to put large UserData contents in CF template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a CloudFormation template for deploying Cisco 8000v instances. In order to bootstrap these I have a very long device-specific user-data file. I can put the whole contents in the UserData block but then my CF template is not very reusable. Can I refer to the contents via a filename and import them somehow? Can't find any examples of this. What is a more common way to approach this? The UserData string as several instance-specific configurations. Should I base64 encode the string and refer to it as a parameter?

Comment: Still not sure what you can do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You would store your long script **externally** to the instance, e.g. in S3. Then your `user_data`, would be very short, limited to downloading the script from S3 and executing it.

Alternatively, you can create [custom ami](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/launch-instance-custom-ami/) which is per-configured for your use-case. This way your use_script can be reduce or even fully eliminated.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use user_data too much, so it is limited with 16KB. check it on [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#:%7E:text=%3A%20Some%20interruptions-,UserData,-The%20user%20data)

Best way to do it. Store it on S3 or another place to your EC2 instance can reach. on `user_data` download and execute it.